# Making an executable jar with Maven/Spring/Eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

So I already tried these:

- Add plugin in pom.xml
- Delete .m2 folder to do a clean package in run as Maven build...
- running mvn clean (on project folder in eclipse IDE)
- Closing and running eclipse again.

The thing is: When I run the main class on eclipse as Java application, the eclipse console shows the app starting up with spring logo. But when I make a Maven build or extract the project as .jar file and try to do java -jar, An exception occurs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at br.com.bancodigimais.keypaypagamentos.portalpos.PortalPosApplication.main(PortalPosApplication.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication at java.base

Why this occurs? I mean...it's possible to make this project to build the jar as executable? When you use the java -jar command and see the spring logo starts the application and so on...

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Portal-POS</groupId>
    <artifactId>Portal-POS</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>            
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     <plugin> 

                <!-- Building an executable jar -->

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>

                    <!-- give full qualified name of your main class-->
                      <mainClass>br.com.bancodigimais.keypaypagamentos.portalpos.PortalPosApplication</mainClass>

                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
    </plugin>
 
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.gradle.plugins.jasper.jspc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv-java8</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-jar-plugin` will create a jar file that contains only your application classes and resources. The jar file will not contain other code that is required to run the application, such as the Spring Boot code including the class `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication`. For this to work you would need to list all dependency jar files with `java -jar <jar-file-path> -cp <list of all dependency jar files>`.

Spring Boot supports executable jar files by packaging the application code and all dependent jars into a single jar file. It also creates the `MANIFEST.MF` entries automatically so you don't need that configuration in your `pom.xml`. There is more information about this in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.first-application.executable-jar) and the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging).

Comment: This is incorrect.  You cannot combine `-jar` and `-cp`.  If you do that, the `-cp` is silently ignored.